# android parse xml - Nodelist has too many objects

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

I had this working, made a change somewhere and now I can't track down the error.

Here's the situation... when _regionList creates, there are 13 regions in the xml file for the region I am using but the _regionlist/children/array has 18 objects. Using a different region (50 elements) it creates with 60 objects.

The remaining objects in the array have a null ID of course, which is the problem. Any thoughts on how additional objects are getting thrown in there?

Thanks

// Parse XML file

```
public void Parse(InputStream inStream, String inRegion) 
{
    try {
        String _region = inRegion;

        this.cFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        this.cBuilder = this.cFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        this.cBuilder.isValidating();

        Document _document = this.cBuilder.parse(inStream, null);

        _document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList _regionList = _document.getElementsByTagName(_region);
        final int _length = _regionList.getLength();

        for (int i = 0; i < _length; i++) {
            final NamedNodeMap _attr = _regionList.item(i).getAttributes();
            final String _regionName = GetNodeValue(_attr, "name");

            // Construct a Region object
            PropertiesRegion _regionObject = new PropertiesRegion(_regionName);

            // Add to list
            this.cList.add(_regionObject);

            Log.d(TAG, _regionObject.toString());
        }
    } 

    catch (SAXException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    catch (ParserConfigurationException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: _document, _regionList and cList all initialize with additional array elements. TrimToSize seems like the appropriate solution but that's not a valid option. Not sure what other options I have to remove the extra array indexes. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additional null indexes in an ArrayList (collection) are fine. The problem is in the TextView and wiring it to the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Other elements in the nodelist are most probably 
, etc, so check node type before proceeding further, may help you to resolve your issue:

```
Node node=_regionList.item(i);
if(node.getNodeType()!=3)
{
       final NamedNodeMap _attr = node.getAttributes();
       final String _regionName = GetNodeValue(_attr, "name");

        // Construct a Region object
        PropertiesRegion _regionObject = new PropertiesRegion(_regionName);

        // Add to list
        this.cList.add(_regionObject);

        Log.d(TAG, _regionObject.toString());

}
```